# why ngForm "controls" property is empty in my test? (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, angular2-forms, angular2-testing

I have a component which employs template-driven form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSearchCorpus(form)" #form="ngForm">
<combo-box [(ngModel)]="model.corpus" name="corpus" #corpus="ngModel"></combo-box>
<input [(ngModel)]="model.label" name="label" id="label" type="text" required pattern="^(?!\s*$)[\w\_\-\:\s]*" maxlength="50" class="form-control label-name" autocomplete="off" #label="ngModel">
<textarea [(ngModel)]="model.query" name="query" id="query" maxlength="3600" required validateQuerySyntax class="form-control search-query" #query="ngModel" #queryControl
        placeholder="Example: (&quot;grantee&quot; OR &quot;grant&quot; OR &quot;sponsor&quot; OR &quot;contribute&quot; OR &quot;contributor&quot;) NEAR (&quot;non-profit organization&quot; OR &quot;charities&quot;)">
      </textarea>
 <button [disabled]="corpusValidationInProgress" type="submit" class="button-level-one">Search</button>
</form>
```

In the method that handles form submission I access [controls](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#controls) property of NgForm instance and it works fine in browser.

```
onSearchCorpus(formData: NgForm) {
   ...
   const corpusErrors = formData.controls.corpus.errors;
   ...
}
```

However when I try to test this method with Karma the NgForm's `controls` property is empty. I'm confused why is that. The method fails with error `cannot read property "errors" of undefined`.

Here is how my test looks like:

```
it('should not perform corpusSearch if selected corpus no longer exists', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    const form = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
    form.triggerEventHandler('submit', null);
    ...
});
```

and this is how I'm setting up my test suit:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        // schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [
            FormsModule,
            PopoverModule
        ],
        providers: [
            CorpusSearchService,
            { provide: ApiService, useValue: ApiServiceStub },
            { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStab },
        ],
        declarations: [
            SearchCorpusComponent, //<--component under test
            ComboBoxComponent //<-- 3rd party combobox which is used for first control 
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchCorpusComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    apiService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ApiService);
    subject = new Subject();
});
```

So, why `controls` is empty in test environment?

Answer (score 11):

The reason why `controls` is "empty" is that the controls were not initialized "yet" in the test environment at the time of calling `onSearchCorpus`.

I've prepared a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EYawvS) (*see `form.component.spec` file*) which demonstrates this issue. In the same file there is also a working solution.

So in short, in order to make this work you need to use `fakeAsync` mechanism.

So instead of:

```
  it('testing form the wrong way', () => {

    fixture.detectChanges();

    comp.onSubmit(); // Validates and submits a form

    expect(comp.submitted).toEqual(false);
  });
```

you should write a test like:

```
  it('testing form the proper way', fakeAsync(() => {

    // This first detectChanges is necessary to properly set up the form
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Tick needs to be called in order for form controls to be registered properly.
    tick();

    comp.onSubmit(); // Validates and submits a form

    expect(comp.submitted).toEqual(false);

  }));
```

Comment: It would be great if Angular's docs had at least a whisper about needing to do this.